# How to link derived class to base class constructor by some forceful requirement in C#

Tags: c#

If I have a derived class and a base class but the base class has arguments required - how can I make it so the derived class mandatory must call the base class with the required parameters?

I'm trying to make the script as easy as possible for some one to write their own code, but it would be quite easy for them to not be aware they HAVE to call base with their own constructor and required arguments or it won't work properly, but there does not appear to be a way force that in the same way you can force abstract methods or interfaces...

This is what i have:

```
public abstract class A { 

   public a {private set; get;}
   public A(){
      this.a = 0;
   }
   public A (int a){
       this.a = a;   // needed to be called
   }   
}
public class B : A 
{ 
 // some user defined class forgets base constructor
}
```

Then they try:

```
B b = new B(someNumber); // error
```

Is there a way to some how contractually state B must call  `: base(someNumber)` from its own constructor some how ?

Comment: Actually, the compiler _will indeed_ force you to have a constructor in the derived class that looks something like this `public B(int a) : base(a) { }`. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Can you please clarify how code in the post does not answer your own question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you got into this mess, but your code didn't compile, and you need to implement the constructor (by law), this how base/derived classes work by design

```
public abstract class A
{

   public int a { private set; get; }

   public A(int a)
   {
      this.a = a; // needed to be called
   }
}

public class B : A
{
   // some user defined class forgets base constructor
   public B(int a) : base(a)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah wait i forgot i had an overload of an empty constructor in A so it was defaulting to that one instead - that would explain it!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Declare a constructor in the base class.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public Base(string param1, string param2)
    {

    }
}
```

Use base class initialization from the derived class constructor. If you don't declare any parameterless default constructor, then the consumer of the derived class will be forced to instantiate the derived class with parameterized constructor & that eventually will hit the base class constructor.

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(string param1, string param2): base(param1, param2)
    {

    }
}
```

For example:

```
//This will first call base class constructor
//then it will hit derived class constructor
Derived derived = new Derived("param1", "param2");
```